# boostrap pull-right not vertically centering button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  Header  |                                |  Button           | --> (using .pull-right) button is not  vertically aligned
----------------------------------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------
|  Header  ||  Button                                           | --> (not using .pull-right) button is vertically aligned
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Using `.pull-right` to pull button to right, but button is not vertically aligned (top margin bigger that bottom) when pulled right.

**Adding `<div class="clearfix"></div>` vertically aligns the button, but then the Header is not vertically aligned(Header's bottom margin too big)**

What's the problem with the .pull-right class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertically align button on pull-right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126211/vertically-align-button-on-pull-right)

Answer (score 1):

`.pull-right` is a helper class for the style value `float: right;`

Read up on how floats affect your layout.

[**css-tricks.com:** All about floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Alternatively you could `.text-right` in the containing element to align your button to the right?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, placing the header and the button in different rows solved it.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    Header      
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="pull-right">
      Button
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```