# Vertically align button on pull-right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list with some items, and every item has a button that I'm trying to right-align using `pull-right`.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p3rd4rkq/

As you can see, the button is not correctly aligned vertically. I've tried setting `line-height: 30px;`, and while this does vertically align the button correctly it also changes the height of the whole list item row. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2vr1o9qn/1/

Is there a better way to align the button and keep the height the same size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then try with `margin-top:-5px;` like this

```
.pull-right {

    margin-top: -5px; //added this
    float: right!important;
}
```

[**Demo Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/p3rd4rkq/1/)

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is:

```
button {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
}
```